# Ratio in first quarter of transformed sine graph

Tags: graphing-functions, ratio

Take a standard sine graph with a period of $4$ such that the first peak is at $x = 1$. Take also the graph $y = x$. Take also a line $y = c - x$.

1. What is the value of $c$ such that the graph it is part of passes through both other graphs and is perpendicular to both at their respective intersections (points $A$ and $B$ for the $\sin$ graph and $y = x$ graph respectively)?
2. What is the ratio between the distance $(0, 0)$ to $(1, 1)$ and $AB$?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the line $y=c-x$ is always orthogonal to $y=x$, the problem reduce to find $c$ such that the line $y=x$ passes through the points $(x_P,y_P)$ of the function $y=\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}x)$ where the slope of the tangent is $m=y'(x_P)=1$.

we have:
$$y'=\frac{\pi}{2}\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}x)=1  $$
so, in the period $[0,4]$ we have the two solutions:
$$x_P=\frac{2}{\pi}\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{2}{\pi}\right)$$
$$
x_{P'}=4-\frac{2}{\pi}\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{2}{\pi}\right)
$$
as you can see in the figure.

[image]

From these we can find the value of $c$ for the lines $y=c-x$ that passes through these points (the red lines in the figure).

Comment: I should have added that the point A is the one closer to y = x. So if I take the solution that yields the lower x value (that corresponding to the point A), then use the function for the sine graph, I will retrieve the coordinates of that intersection. Then I find c from there, then the intersection with y = x, and then 2 sets of coordinates from which I can get the ratio in part 2?

This is extremely useful. Thank you.

Comment: The ratio is approximately 7:94